# Unsequence Monad function within Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell, monads, reverse

I'm having some real trouble designing the counterfunction of Haskell's `sequence` function, which Hoogle tells me doesn't yet exist. This is how it behaves:

```
ghci> sequence [Just 7, Just 8, Just 9]
Just [7,8,9]
ghci> sequence [getLine, getLine, getLine]
hey
there
stack exchange
["hey","there","stack exchange"] :: IO [String]
```

My problem is making a function like this:

```
unsequence :: (Monad m) => m [a] -> [m a]
```

So that it behaves like this:

```
ghci> unsequence (Just [7, 8, 9])
[Just 7, Just 8, Just 9]
ghci> sequence getLine
hey
['h','e','y'] :: [IO Char] --(This would actually cause an error, but hey-ho.)
```

I don't actually know if that's possible, because I'd be escaping the monad at some point, but I've made a start, though I don't know how to set a breakpoint for this recursive function:

```
unsequence m = (m >>= return . head) : unsequence (m >>= return . tail)
```

I realise that I need a breakpoint when the `m` here is equal to `return []`, but not all monads have `Eq` instances, so how can I do this? Is this even possible? If so, why and why not? Please tell me that.

Comment: To see why it can't be done in general, consider something like `do { b <- check; if b then list1 else list2 } :: M [A]` for some concrete monad `M` and some concrete type `A`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is indeed not possible to create an `unsequence` function using monads alone. The reason is:

1. You can safely and easily create a monadic structure from a value using `return`.
2. However, it is not safe to remove a value from a monadic structure. For example you can't remove an element from an empty list (i.e. a function of the type `[a] -> a` is not safe).
3. Hence we have a special function (i.e. `>>=`) which safely removes a value from a monadic structure (if one exists), processes it and returns another safe monadic structure.

Hence it is safe to create a monadic structure from a value. However it is not safe to remove a value from a monadic structure.

Suppose we had a function `extract :: Monad m => m a -> a` which could “safely” remove a value from a monadic structure. We could then implement `unsequence` as follows:

```
unsequence :: Monad m => m [a] -> [m a]
unsequence = map return . extract
```

However, there's no safe way to extract a value from a monadic structure. Hence `unsequence []` and `unsequence Nothing` will return `undefined`.

You can however create an `unsequence` function for structures that are both monadic and comonadic. A `Comonad` is defined as follows:

```
class Functor w => Comonad w where
    extract   :: w a -> a
    duplicate :: w a -> w (w a)
    extend    :: (w a -> b) -> w a -> w b

    duplicate = extend id
    extend f = fmap f . duplicate
```

A comonadic structure is the opposite of a monadic structure. In particular:

1. You can safely extract a value from a comonadic structure.
2. However you can't safely create a new comonadic structure from a value, which is why the `duplicate` function safely creates a new comonadic structure from a value.

Remember that the definition of `unsequence` required both `return` and `extract`? You can't safely create a new comonadic structure from a value (i.e. comonadic structures don't have `return`). Hence the `unsequence` function is defined as follows:

```
unsequence :: (Comonad m, Monad m) => m [a] -> [m a]
unsequence = map return . extract
```

Interestingly `sequence` works on simply monadic structures. So via intuition you might assume that `unsequence` works on simply comonadic structures. However it not so because you need to first extract the list from the comonadic structure and then put each element of the list into a monadic structure.

The general version of the `unsequence` function converts a comonadic list structure to a list of monadic structures:

```
unsequence :: (Comonad w, Monad m) => w [a] -> [m a]
unsequence = map return . extract
```

On the other hand the `sequence` function works on simply monadic structures because you are just folding the list of monadic structures into a monadic list structure by chaining all the monads:

```
import Control.Monad (liftM2)

sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
sequence = foldr (liftM2 (:)) (return [])
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I see a problem with using your `unsequence` when used with WriterMonad. It looses all the state. If there is a way to implement it so the stat is duplicated from original one to every list element?

Comment: Follow-up questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660343/writermonad-unsequence

Answer (score 11):

You can't have an `unsequence :: (Monad m) => m [a] -> [m a]`. The problem lies with lists: you can't be sure how may elements you are going to get with a list, and that complicates any reasonable definition of `unsequence`.

Interestingly, if you were absolutely, **100%** sure that the list inside the monad is infinite, you could write something like:

```
unsequenceInfinite :: (Monad m) => m [a] -> [m a]
unsequenceInfinite x = fmap head x : unsequenceInfinite (fmap tail x)
```

And it would work!

Also imagine that we have a `Pair` functor lying around. We can write `unsequencePair` as

```
unsequencePair :: (Monad m) => m (Pair a) -> Pair (m a)
unsequencePair x = Pair (fmap firstPairElement x) (fmap secondPairElement x)
```

In general, it turns out you can only define `unsequence` for functors with the property that you can always "zip" together two values without losing information. Infinite lists (in Haskell, one possible type for them is [`Cofree Identity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.10.0.1/docs/Control-Comonad-Cofree.html)) are an example. The `Pair` functor is another. But not conventional lists, or functors like `Maybe` or `Either`.

In the [`distributive`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.4.4/docs/Data-Distributive.html#v:collect) package, there is a typeclass called `Distributive` that encapsulates this property. Your `unsequence` is called `distribute` there.