# Convert a function returning a list to a list of functions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a function `f :: Int -> [a]` which always returns a list of size `n`, like so:

```
f 0 = [a_0_1, a_0_2, ..., a_0_n]
f 1 = [a_1_1, a_1_2, ..., a_1_n]
.
.
.
f k = [a_k_1, a_k_2, ..., a_k_n]
```

I want to transform this into a list of functions:

```
[f_1, f_2, ..., f_n] :: [Int -> a]
```

where

```
f_k i = a_i_k
```

I hope the notation I've used is clear enough to convey what I want.

Comment: How did you end up in this situation to begin with? Where does `f` come from and why do you need to transform it so?

Comment: @dfeuer I'm making a polynomial solver for polynomials with computable real coefficients. Real numbers are represented as a convergent rational sequence. `f k` is a list of the kth terms in the sequences representing the roots. To transform this into n different sequences, with each one representing a root, I need to do the above transformation.

Comment: How are you calculating `f i`? When in the course of your program do you find out how large you want `k` and `n` to be?

Comment: @dfeuer I take a rational approximation of the coefficients to a sufficient accuracy, then use a standard root finding algorithm to compute the roots to a sufficient accuracy. `n`, the number of distinct real roots the polynomial has, is found by just counting the size of `f 0`. `k` is determined when a number using the root is printed, and will likely be very large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambdas

```
fn = [(\k -> (f k)!!i) | i <- [0..n - 1]]
```

then

```
[f1, f2, f3, ...] = fn
```

but you should analyze your general problem (this approach is slow).

Complete sandbox code:

```
n = 5

f k = [2 * k + i | i <- [1..n]]

fn = [(\k -> (f k)!!i) | i <- [0..n - 1]]

(f1:f2:_) = fn

main = do

    print $ f 4
    print $ (fn!!3) 4
    print $ f2 4
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking this recomputes `f k` for each i? If so, would there be any way of doing this while only computing `f k` once? (calls to `f` are fairly expensive)

Comment: `f1`...`fn` are lazy, only will be computed when evaluated. Also, once computed, each `f1` are computed only one time. The problem, is how `f` works to return all values (when only one is needed), this can not be optimized without know `f` inside.

Comment: Your code does recompute `f k` for each `i`. It's easy to fix this, however: `fn f = map (\i k -> fs !! k !! i) [0..] where fs = map f [0..]` Compare [this](http://ideone.com/UZ1DFD) and [this](http://ideone.com/hUGwaz), and also [this](http://ideone.com/QwIa6t) and [this](http://ideone.com/XeeJ46)

Comment: "recompute `f k`". Of course, the internal computation is recomputed if you do here `f2 4` and there `f2 4`. That's no the question "Convert a function returning a list to a list of functions". In fact, your functions could be `IO` then. Recomputation is needed! :D If you wish avoid recomputation, precompute or memoize (as in `where fs...`). With `f1` are computed only one time I said `f1` not `f1 3`. "this can not be optimized without know f inside" ;)

Comment: You can return an `IO` action, but you can't run it due to referential transparency. Recomputation is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
f 0 = [a_0_0, a_0_1 ... a_0_m]
f 1 = [a_1_0, a_1_1 ... a_1_m]
...
f n = [a_n_0, a_n_1 ... a_n_m]
```

then

```
matr = transpose $ map f [0..n]
```

gives you

```
[ [a_0_0, a_1_0 ... a_n_0]
, [a_0_1, a_1_1 ... a_n_1]
...
, [a_0_m, a_1_m ... a_n_m]
]
```

Your equation is `f_j i = a_i_j`, where `i` ranges over `[0..n]` and `j` ranges over `[0..m]`.

Since, `matr` is transposed, the equation becomes `f_j i = matr_j_i`, which can be reflected as follows:

```
map (\j i -> matr !! j !! i) [0..]
```

The whole function is

```
transform f n = map (\j i -> matr !! j !! i) [0..] where
    matr = transpose $ map f [0..n]
```

Or just

```
transform f n = map (!!) $ transpose $ map f [0..n]
```

**EDIT**

As @josejuan pointed out, this code is not efficient, since, while evaluating

```
(transform f n !! j) i
```

`transpose` forces `f i'` for all `i' <= i`.

Comment: Your `transpose $ map f [0..n]` compute all `j*n` chunks for one `f_j` call when only `j+i` is needed for one `f_j i` call. For bigs `n` (or intensive recalls) you will may get bad performance. (This may not matter).

Comment: How you are accessing to `35` value without thunk `32, 29, ...` values? :) You can not assume `f` is efficient to return `35` (`34, 33, 32, 31 and 30`) without compute some (not lazy) over previous values (the `32, 29, ...`). With `transpose` you are forzing to evaluate each `f_j` (not all `n`) and you can't assume this evaluation is efficient. Then, the worst case is `j*n` (compute `j` times `f`) instead `j+i` (compute once `f_j` and traverse `i`).

Comment: Using your example, you can watch your intermediate thunked values (`32, 29, ...` on my previous comment) https://gist.github.com/josejuan/29531e9a9a84f4ad6477 (and how is `j*n`)

Comment: @josejuan, ah, yes. `:sprint` confused me a lot. Thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by actually applying the function to all these values:

```
listf = map f [0..k]
```

So

```
listf = [[a_0_1, a_0_2, ..., a_0_n]
        ,[a_1_1, a_1_2, ..., a_1_n]
        ,...
        ,[a_k_1, a_k_2, ..., a_k_n]]
```

Now we have a list of lists, but it's the wrong way around. So let's take the transpose:

```
listft = transpose listf

listft = [[a_0_1, a_1_1, ..., a_k_1]
         ,[a_0_2, a_1_2, ..., a_k_2]
         ,...
         ,[a_0_n, a_1_n, ..., a_k_n]]
```

Now we have a list of lists, and each of the inner lists represents an `f_i` for some `i`. But we don't want to stop with that representation, because actually calculating the `j`th element of a list is `O(j)`. So let's use `Vector`, from `Data.Vector`, instead:

```
listmapsf = map fromList listft
```

Now we have a list of `Vector`s, each of which represents an `f_i`. We can turn those into functions using `!`:

```
functions = map (!) listmapsf
```

Note: this does absolutely nothing to verify that the input lists are all the same length. It's probably also not the most efficient way to produce the list of functions, but it's not a bad one.

Edit: per user3237465's suggestion, I've replaced the `IntMap` representation with a `Vector` one.

Comment: Why not vectors or arrays then?

Comment: How come accessing the `j`th element isn't `O(j)` any more? Does the compiler eliminate the intermediate representation? (I've just started learning haskell, so I might be mis-understanding something).

Comment: @CameronMartin, it's still going to be `O(j)` to access the `j`th function in the list, and it's still going to be `O(n*k)` to build the list of functions. But each function will now be `O(1)`. If you start with a different representation (not a function producing lists), you may very well be able to do better.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question, and deserves to be applied to an arbitrary function of general type `a -> [b]`.

I actually made a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342863/unsequence-monad-function-within-haskell) about the monadic `sequence` function, regarding making an opposite, an `unsequence` function. It was shown to be **impossible**. Here's why:

When a function returns a list, it may be of an arbitrary length. This means that we can only determine the length of the returned list when we call the function. As a result, we cannot make a list of fixed length without calling the function.

A simpler way of understanding this is imagining that we've got values trapped in an IO monad. of type `IO [Int]`. This is perfectly comparable to `a -> [Int]` because both values can only be manipulated while they're kept inside their monadic type. This is different for the `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]` because the `[a]` monad can be deconstructed, i.e: it's a comonad too.

To put it simply, 'pure' monads can only be constructed, and thus you cannot take a list's length, which is fundamental if we are to construct a list, from inside a function monad, or and IO monad. I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need all of the values don't compute them until they are needed. You just need to define indexed access, i.e.  `let frc r c = f!!r!!c` where `r` is the row and `c` is the column.